# BackboneJS: iterate on model attribute and change value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-model

I want to make a function with functionality like `toJSON()`'s functionality which returns and edits model.

My question is how to iterate on model's attribute and edit the specific value of the attribute you selected.

If have a model e.g:

```
Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        amount: 0.00
    },
    toHTML: function(){
        // i think this is the place where
        // where i can do that function?

        //
        console.log(this.attribute)
    }
});
var item = new Item;

item.set({name: 'Pencil', amount: 5}): 

item.toJSON();
-> {name: 'Pencil', amount: 5}

// this is the function
item.toHTML();
-> {name: 'Pencil', amount: 5.00}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over an object using a [`for ... in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and then use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format the number:

```
toHTML: function() {
    var attrs = { }, k;
    for(k in this.attributes) {
        attrs[k] = this.attributes[k];
        if(k === 'amount')
           attrs[k] = attrs[k].toFixed(2);
    }
    return attrs;
}
```

Note that `amount` will come out as a string but that's the only way to get `5.00` rather than `5` to come out. I'd probably leave the formatting up to the template and not bother with this `toHTML` implementation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ELTe5/

Comment: cooool! thanks for helping noobs like us!
my plan is make the rendering lik e this --> this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toHTML()));

Comment: That will work and having a separate "serialize for templates" method (such as your `toHTML`) so that `toJSON` can be used to talk to the server is a good idea. I'd probably leave the `toFixed` call up to the template though.

Comment: yup! `toHTML` is for rendering purpose only. If ever the amount value in my `toHTML` is `1,550.00` the `toJSON` still have `1500.00` value, and the `toFixed` i tried to make a custom because `toFixed` not realible. anyway, thanks a lot for the help! cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to iterate over a model's attributes, use the [`attributes`](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-attributes) hash:

```
// Inside your model's method
for(attr in this.attributes){
    console.log(attr, this.attributes[attr]);
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/520/) using your example code.

Answer (score 4):

Though the answers provided here are correct and would do what you want. But I think the better way would be to use the underscore functions for this purpose.
for simple looping you can use

```
_.each(list, iteratee, [context])

_.each(model.attributes, function(item, index, items){
  console.log(item);
  console.log(index);
})
```

you can also use specialized functions as per your specific need. Like if you are want to have a new result array as a result of applying some function on every element of your list, map can be the best option for you.

```
_.map(list, iteratee, [context])

var newList = _.map(model.attributes, function(item, index, list){
  return item * 5;
})
```

I would recommend you to go through the documentation of underscore and backbone for the best function for your need.